# Hibernate Parent Child association

Tags: java, hibernate

As the title suggest, I am facing some issues in designing and performing basic CRUD operations using hibernate for parent child association. My scenario is as follows :

**POJO**

**User.java**

```
public class User {
    private int uid;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String email;
    private int phone;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

**ProUser.java**

```
public class ProUser extends User{
    private String company;
    private String position;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

**TABLES :**

**USER**

```
CREATE TABLE USER (
    UID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NAME VARCHAR(20),
    ADDRESS VARCHAR(100),
    EMAIL VARCHAR(50),
    PHONE INT
)
```

**PRO_USER**

```
CREATE TABLE PRO_USER (
    UID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    COMPANY VARCHAR(20),
    POSITION VARCHAR(20),
    FOREIGN KEY (UID) REFERENCES USER (UID) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Now, the design has to be like this. The user table gets the record whether its a simple user or a pro user. When its a pro user, just additional data is stored in PRO_USER table, having the common fields to be stored in USER table.
After studying some hibernate approaches, I used **table per subclass mapping strategy XML**. I was able to INSERT records, which was simple as if I just save a user object it saves it in USER table only and if I save a prouser object then it saves in both USER table and PRO_USER table.

**Code :**

 I am not mentioning the **hibernate.cfg.xml** code, which is basic for every hibernate application. And for this scenario I have mapped only **user.hbm.xml** as a resource.

**user.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.vsharma.entity">

<class name="User" table="USER">
    <id name="uid" column="UID">
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>

    <property name="name" column="NAME" />
    <property name="address" column="ADDRESS" />
    <property name="email" column="EMAIL" />
    <property name="phone" column="PHONE" />

    <joined-subclass name="ProUser" extends="User">
            <key column="UID" />
            <property name="company" column="COMPANY" />
            <property name="position" column="POSITION" />
    </joined-subclass>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**MainApp.java**
    package com.vsharma;

```
import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.cfg.*;
import com.vsharma.entity.*;

public class MainApp {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

    SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession(); 

    User normal = new User();
         normal.setName("XXX");
         normal.setAddress("123 Street");
         normal.setEmail("blahblah@test.com");
         normal.setPhone(1234567890);

    ProUser pro = new ProUser();
         pro.setName("YYY");
         pro.setAddress("456 Street");
         pro.setEmail("problah@test.com");
         pro.setPhone(9876543210);
         pro.setCompany("ABC Tech");
         pro.setPosition("Testter");

    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(normal); // This saves only in USER Table
    session.save(pro);     // This saves in both USER and PRO_USER Table
    System.out.println("Object saved successfully.....!!");
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
    factory.close();
}
```

This serves the purpose for insertion but I am not confused in retrieving the data using only uid and also update and delete. How is the SELECT, DELETE and UPDATE operations will be performed in java code ? I don't know that the incoming recordset is a normal user or a prouser. I have googled the google, and I found no article/post that demonstrates all CRUD Operations. May be the technique I am using to fulfill the requirement is not appropriate, so I request people here to sought out my problem, or suggest me other strategy that can serve the whole purpose.
**It would a great help literally and thanks in advance.**

Comment: http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-with-foreign-key-xml-mapping-example read this article may be this will helpfull

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example that shows the CRUD operations:

### - Select

You can use `HQL` or `Criteria` to do select operations:

```
    Query query = session.createQuery("from User user where user.uid=:uid");
    query.setInteger("uid", 2);
    User user = (User) query.uniqueResult();
    System.out.println("User name before update = " + user.getName());

    // Here just check the type of object and do the explicit casting to access child properties.

    if(user instanceof ProUser){
        System.out.println(((ProUser) user).getCompany());
    }
```

Now showing the other operations that are based on below query:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from User user where user.uid=:uid");
query.setInteger("uid", 1);
```

### - Update

Once you select an entity you can call `session.update()` method to update the entity:

```
User user = (User) query.uniqueResult();
System.out.println("User name before update = " + user.getName());
user.setName("ZZZ");
session.update(user);
```

### - Delete

You can just call `session.delete` method by passing the entity and delete the record from DB.

```
User user = (User) query.uniqueResult();
System.out.println("User name before delete = " + user.getName());
session.delete(user);
```

Here is a sample program:

```
private static void updateUser() {
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from User user where user.uid=:uid");
    query.setInteger("uid", 1);
    User user = (User) query.uniqueResult();
    System.out.println("User name before update = " + user.getName());
    user.setName("ZZZ");
    tx.commit();
    session.close();    
}

private static void deleteUser(Session session) {
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from User user where user.uid=:uid");
    query.setInteger("uid", 2);
    User user = (User) query.uniqueResult();
    System.out.println("User name before delete = " + user.getName());
    session.delete(user);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();    
}
```

As per your program the uid 2 represents a record f `PROUSER` so data will be in both the tables `USER` & `PROUSER`. So in my example if you query the DB with `UID` as `2` and then deleting the entity means you are telling hibernate to delete the records whose id is `2` from both the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Use below example code for CRUD operation

```
// for create

Contact contact1 = new Contact("Nam", "hainatuatgmail.com", "Vietnam", "0904277091");
session.persist(contact1);
Contact contact2 = new Contact("Bill", "billatgmail.com", "USA", "18001900");
Serializable id = session.save(contact2);
System.out.println("created id: " + id);


//for Read
Contact contact = (Contact) session.get(Contact.class, new Integer(2));
if (contact == null) {
    System.out.println("There is no Contact object with id=2");
} else {
    System.out.println("Contact3's name: " + contact.getName());
}



//To update a detached instance, call either the update() or saveOrUpdate() method, for example:

Contact contact = new Contact("Jobs", "jobsatapplet.com", "Cupertino", "0123456789");
session.update(contact);


//To delete an object with a given identifier, use the delete() method, for example:

Contact contactToDelete = new Contact();
contactToDelete.setId(4);
session.delete(contactToDelete);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replys, but again I got errors when I tried to fetch with uid say 2.
In ur program

```
User user = (User) session.load(User.class, new Integer(2));
```

This would give error since the hibernate knows its a `ProUser` record it has inserted but considering its not known on java code side which type of object is coming, changing this to

```
ProUser pro =  (ProUser) session.load(ProUser.class, new Integer(2));
```

This might work, but what if I pass `uid 1` to this one, again for hibernate `uid 1` is a normal user record....

Comment: you should not add this as an answer , if you have any issues then you need to update your question and if you want to say something then you should add as a comment to a particular answer

Comment: Now coming back to your new issue, what you wanted to do is just a simple Java thing not specific to hibernate. You need to check the object type using `instanceof` keyword. I have updated my answer on how can you do that.

Comment: You are already casting the load operation to User, the object will of type User always...then using instanceof has no meaning.

Comment: No your assumption is completely wrong. please go through the java docs and learn how `instanceof` operator works. Also try the code which I have posted, there is no issue and it will work perfectly.

Comment: can you post the exact code that you have tried so I can see if there is any issue. Also note that using instanceof works perfectly as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Thanks it worked somehow, I had to use Query api to get data from USER table only, instead of using
**User u = (User) HibernateTemplate().get(User.class, new Integer(2))**
By using query I execute select statement explicitly, but internally Hibernate still does a join besides changing the attribute **lazy="true"** in mapping file.
I collect them in a list of type User, and then apply instanceof and it worked fine, Hibernate internally get to know that which is ProUser and which is regular User.

Comment: I think it is better you learn hibernate by reading some book or online docs, because that is how hibernate works. If you are satisfied with my answer then accept it as correct answer

Comment: Most of the online documents, articles, post end up with just explaining the concept which is okay to understand, but real problem is on implementation like the one I posted here.
I used Table per subclass Hibernate inheritance, and all the articles have just INSERT operation and got stuck at SELECT, DELETE and UPDATE.

Comment: And to be honest, try your code, it will give errors for sure. that is why I had to do some dirty workaround.

Comment: dude can you tell exactly where you are getting errors and what are they? I am have tested it on my machine before posting it in SO. Also what is that "dirty" workaround you did?

Comment: by the way regarding SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE thing, there is nothing special we should do to use them, you can see my answer, if we know java and basic operations of hibernate then we can implement them ourselves.

Comment: Also I forgot to tell you, in the answer you posted in SO which has issues, you are not supposed to explicitly cast anything to child classes (ProUser in your example) when you retrieve something from DB using hibernate. You have to take it as super class then do the checking if the object type is of particular subclass and then only you have to do explicit casting as we generally do in inheritence concept, that is why `instanceof` operator works in my code.